# How can I decorate column images and text in an SWT TableViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have an SWT table that is wrapped with a JFace `TableViewer`.

My requirements are:

1. Decorate the column image with the decorators as they are defined in the workbench decorator manager
2. Decorate the text of the columns with different colors

I was able to #1 by extending `DecoratingLabelProvider` and implementing `ITableLabelProvider`. I passed it my original `TableLabelProvider` and the workbench decorator manager, and I got icons with decorators.

Then I started to work on #2. I asked this question here and was told that `IStyleLabelProvider` (what I was trying to use for the colored text) was incompatible with `ITableLabelProvider`. So I switched to using a `ColumnLabelProvider` that implements `IStyledLabelProvider`.

However, now I am stuck. These 2 requirements seem to be mutually exclusive. I cannot extend both `ColumnLabelProvider` and `DecoratingLabelProvider`. When I tried to simply pass in the workbench decorator manager to the `ColumnLabelProvider` like this, but it did not decorate the image at all. Did I pass it in wrong, or will that only work in a `DecoratingLabelProvider`? What else can I try?

```
    public Image getColumnImage(final Object element, final int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == MY_COLUMN_INDEX) {
            final MyObject myObj = (MyObject) element;
            final Image image = myObj .getImage();
            Image newImage = null;
            if(this.decorator != null) {
                newImage = this.decorator.decorateImage(image, myObj );
            }
            return newImage == null ? image : newImage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` which takes an `IStyledLabelProvider` and an `ILabelDecorator` as parameters:

```
new DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider(styledLabelProvider,
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager()
                            .getLabelDecorator(), null);
```

Comment: Wow. That was too simple. The funny thing is that I've used this class before. I don't know how I forgot about it. It worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: There are so many label provider classes it is hard to remember them all.